# Text size in pt doesn't work on Samsung Galaxy S2 i9108

Tags: android, galaxy

I created a Hello World app from scratch. Its layout contains one TextView, which did not specify a `android:textSize` value, it shows fine on screen on a real device. I added a few more, which explicitly specify text sizes in points, they all appear very very very small, almost invisible.

```
<!-- Without textSize given. This one shows fine. -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<!-- These have a different size, in points. They are invisible. -->
<TextView
    android:textSize="12pt"
    android:text="Hello world, 12pt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    android:textSize="16pt"
    android:text="Hello world, 16pt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

As a further test, I put a few sizes in the `res.values` folder and access them programmatically:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="fontSize">8pt</dimen>
    <dimen name="height">60dp</dimen>
</resources>
......
......
i = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fontSize); // returns 1
i = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.height); // returns 90
```

Samsung Galaxy S2 i9108's density is 240dpi, so 60dp equates to 90 pixel is expected. But for all sizes in points, they seem to be translated to very small values. Does anybody have an idea? Thanks in advance.

This app has a `minSDKVersion="10"`, which is what i9108 is. So I don't think this would be a problem. And, this app runs fine on emulator, but not on a real device.

(I don't have the real device in hand, testing is tough. So I haven't done a lot of tests so far.)

Does anybody have an idea? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you remember to add which device screen sizes is supported in your manifest? This is important.

Comment: @Warpzit Thanks for response. In my real app (the above was only a test app for this bug), Market identifies that it supports SMALL, NORMAL, LARGE, XLARGE. I guess this is it, am I right?

Comment: Based on documentation 1pt is 1/72inch on device screen so you could do some quick testing if this holds by using "in" as reference.

Comment: No not market. In the manifest you should set which screen sizes it supports, if you don't it might run it in compatability mode depending on which version you run.

Comment: @harism Yes, I was thinking that if when worse comes to worst, I may have to change "pt" to "dp" or "in" like you mentioned. But I don't have the device in hand, so testing is tough. And because this is an app of 48K lines, I'm hoping for a better solution.

Comment: I have SGS2 I9100 if it's any help, and R.dimen.fontSize returns 24 pixels.

Comment: @harism Thank you so much for taking the time!!!! Noted.

Answer (score 2):

Through the help of my user, I confirmed that Samsung Galaxy S2 i9108 has a "bug" that it doesn't translate measurements in pt correctly. As for dp and sp, they are correctly translated. I don't want to spend time on why pt is incorrect, we'll just change all font sizes to dp, or sp, haven't decided yet. (We didn't use sp in the first place was for a reason.)

This seems to happen to i9108 only, I have users of i9100 confirm that our app was all right on their phones. So I assume this is a i9108-specific problem.

A big thank-you to all those who responded me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For text sizes it is recommended to use `sp` unit measure which is screen density independent and also can be scaled by font size.

For more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension